# how to make tabs support zDepth like AppBar

Tags: material-ui

want to draw shadow on bottom of tabs

```html
<Tabs
  onChange={this.handleTabChange}
  value={this.state.slideIndex}
  style={?}
>
  <Tab label="Label" value={0} style={or here?} ></Tab>
</Tabs>
```

how to write the styles
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're referring to [Material UI](http://www.material-ui.com/), I believe [Tabs](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/tabs) do not have a zDepth property as the [AppBar](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/app-bar) does. Best to fold the Tab component into the AppBar.

You can add it manually, however, with:

```
style={{boxShadow: '0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)'}}
```